# How to have axios timeout setup correctly in React-native

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using axios in React-native, how to setup timeout?

```
axios.create(
    baseURL: 'https://dd.com/',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
```

Am I doing it right? because it doesn't correctly.

Comment: First issue is missing `{`

Comment: `axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://dd.com/',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })`